# Current Location displayed at false on-screen coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm just trying to make sense of a basic Android navigation-related question, namely "How can I display the current location". I've used a bit of code from articles and tutorials from my long googling sessions. The display of a simple overlay (circle + text message) is works, yet at a wrong on-screen position (on the Equator apparently).

My code setup includes a small inner class that `implements LocationListener`, and its `onLocationChanged` event handler calls this method :

```
protected void createAndShowCustomOverlay(Location newLocation) 
{
  double lat = newLocation.getLatitude();
  double lng = newLocation.getLongitude();

  // geoPointFromLatLng is an E6 converter :
  // return new GeoPoint((int) (pLat * 1E6), (int) (pLng * 1E6));  
  GeoPoint geopoint = GeoFunctions.geoPointFromLatLng(lat, lng);

  CustomOverlay overlay = new CustomOverlay(geopoint);

  mapView.getOverlays().add(overlay);
  mapView.getController().animateTo(geopoint);

  mapView.postInvalidate();
}
```

Up to this point, it all looks ok, I've debugged around and the non-transformed lat/lng pair is ok, the E6 variant thereof ok as well. Here is the CustomOverlay class :

```
public class CustomOverlay extends Overlay 
{

  private static final int CIRCLERADIUS = 2;
  private GeoPoint geopoint;

  public CustomOverlay(GeoPoint point) 
  {
    geopoint = point;
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) 
  {
    // Transfrom geoposition to Point on canvas
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    Point point = new Point();
    projection.toPixels(geopoint, point);

    // background
    Paint background = new Paint();
    background.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    RectF rect = new RectF();
    rect.set(point.x + 2 * CIRCLERADIUS, point.y - 4 * CIRCLERADIUS,
       point.x + 90, point.y + 12);

    // text "My Location"
    Paint text = new Paint();
    text.setAntiAlias(true);
    text.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    text.setTextSize(12);
    text.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);

     // the circle to mark the spot
     Paint circle = new Paint();
     circle.setColor(Color.BLUE);
     circle.setAntiAlias(true);

     canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 2, 2, background);
     canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, CIRCLERADIUS, circle);
     canvas.drawText("My Location", point.x + 3 * CIRCLERADIUS, point.y + 3
                     * CIRCLERADIUS, text);
   }
}
```

It's most definitely a projection error of sorts, since all my geo fix'd coords end up on the Equator, so there are some 0.0 values getting thrown around.

I can provide other details if needed, I'm running the code on the emulator, Maps API Level 8 (Android 2.2) and I get tiles and the CustomOverlay (circle + text) gets displayed, only at a really false position (coords such as 54.foo and 8.bar are way off).

The codebase could be a bit older, then perhaps a projection such as `toPixels` isn't required anymore ? No idea.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, turns out the "geo fix" command sent via telnet wants a (Lng, Lat) pair, not a (Lat, Lng) pair. Inconsistency at its best ! Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show current location and keep it updating with a small blinking circule on the screen like Google Maps for Android does, then Android has a default implementation of this feature.

```
    MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(context, mapView);
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
```

That's it Android will handle everything.

Comment: I've tried that before, thanks for the input. What's the format I have to send the coords in ? 

I think sending the wrongfully formatted coordinates was my problem, all the lat/lng pairs I've seen usually have a negative lat value (e.g. geo fix -82.411629 28.054553), why is that ?

Comment: Yeah turns out you have to telnet them, using the built-in stuff from Eclipse yields not so good results. It works using revised and properly inputted lat/lng pairs. Thanks again !

Comment: Oh, wow matter of fact geo fix wants (lng, lat), not (lat, lng) -- as in the way almost every geo-related app handles coords.